# Scala Slick value foreach is not a member of

Tags: scala, for-loop, foreach, slick

This is in a Scala Play project using to connect to MariaDB.

```
cat build.sbt
...
jdbc,
"org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "2.6.2",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.2",
...
```

```scala
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(...)](tag, "USERS") {...}

val users = TableQuery[Users]

for (u <- users) {...}
```

Error:

```
value foreach is not a member of slick.lifted.TableQuery[controller.Users]

for (u <- users) {
          ^
```

I tried adding `.result` to `users` in the for loop, but I got

```
value foreach is not a member of slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.StreamingProfileAction[Seq[controller.Users#TableElementType],controller.Users#TableElementType,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]

for (u <- users.result) {
                ^
```

I don't have `db.run` anywhere in the code.

Comment: A `for` comprehension without a `yield` clause compiles info a `.foreach()` call on your collection. If your collection doesn't support a `foreach()` method then you have to use a different means to iterate over the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to iterate over the users in your database.

There are a couple of concepts that you need here:

- The expression `users` is a kind of query. Methods like `map` and `filter` are a way to produce alternative queries. Iterating over a *query*, with a `foreach`, doesn't really make sense.
- With `users.results` you have an action (a kind of `DBIOAction`). This is something you might send to the database, with a `db.run`. Again, methods like `map` or `flatMap` are a way to convert and combine actions, but iterating over *an action* with `foreach`, doesn't really make sense.

So what to do? The signature of `users.result` is something like `DBIO[Seq[User]]`. If you want to do something to each user, maybe print them out, you can construct an action to do that. One way is to `map` the result of the action (a list of users) to something else. Maybe:

```
val doSomethingWithEachUser: DBIO[Unit] = 
  users.result.map { seqUsers => 
    seqUsers.foreach(println)
  }
```

Here we've used `map` to change the result type of the `DBIO[Seq[User]]` into a `DBIO[Unit]`.

You can then send `doSomethingWithEachUser` to the database (so to speak) with `db.run`. When you do that, your action is run, and when the values are available, the `println` will happen.

To switch back to a for comprehension, you can see that we need to construct a new action:

```
val doSomethingWithEachUser: DBIO[Unit] =
  for {
    allUsers <- messages.result
  } yield allUsers.foreach(println)
```

...for example.

The next layer on would be in `Future`, which is the result from `db.run`. You could also use a `map` (or similar) on a future to work with the data. Slick is pretty much all about these kinds of building blocks of queries, actions, and (finally) futures, and manipulating them with combinators like `map` and `flatMap`.